# How can I delete EF entities in a performant way?

Tags: .net, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have the following (simplified) EF model, which I am accessing with RIA services:

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> { get; set;}
}
```

I would expect when I delete a department from my DomainContext, that the referenced Employees are deleted as well. Basically a cascade delete, handled by EF.

Now I found 2 ways to achieve this:

**1. Enable Cascade Delete at the database level:**

I'd really, really not like to do this if possible at all.

**2. Load the child entities (Employees) at runtime (currently implemented):**

When the user wants to delete a Department, the Employees are loaded into a list, iterated over and deleted from the context. I cannot help but feel this is clunky, it works however...

Any thoughts on the proper way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned both ways supported by EF. If you don't like them you need stored procedure - there is no better way. In case of EF most common solution is cascade delete.

Comment: It just feels wrong to load all child entities (or maybe an entire entity tree) to just delete them. I mean, if EF knows the parent entity type and child type, it should be able to easily construct a *DELETE FROM [childtable] where [parentId] = id*... Right?

Comment: But EF doesn't do it and because of that everybody is using cascade delete because it is the same.